# Laravel Elixr copy method not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am trying to copy some js files, using elixr, from my vendor/bower_components folder, but when running gulp they don't copy across.

```
elixir(function(mix) { mix.less('app.less')
  .copy('underscore/underscore.js', 'public/js/vendor/underscore.js'); });
```

No error is given by gulp.

```
[14:12:58] Using gulpfile ~/Public/balloonprinting_l5/gulpfile.js
[14:12:58] Starting 'default'... 
[14:12:58] Starting 'less'... 
[14:12:58] Running Less: resources/assets/less/app.less 
[14:12:59] Finished 'default' after 506 ms 
[14:13:00] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Less Compiled! 
[14:13:00] Finished 'less' after 1.74 s 
[14:13:00] Starting 'copy'... 
[14:13:00] Finished 'copy' after 2.86 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify full source path:

```
elixir(function(mix) { mix.less('app.less')
  .copy(
    'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js', 
    'public/js/vendor/underscore.js'
  ); 
});
```

As you can see I added `bower_components/` to source path, this is default bower packages folder.

Comment: thanks for the response. No, that still didn't work. Also, according to the documentation, you shouldn't need to set that. It should default to that, as per the node_modules/laravel-elixir/Config.js file: bowerDir: 'vendor/bower_components',

Comment: yeah, it's ``vendor/bower_components``, default bower path is ``bower_components``, without ``vendor/``.

Comment: I have just set the full path 'vendor/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js' and it worked. Again though, unless I have misunderstood the documentation, this shouldn't be required.

Comment: there are only examples with full path in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir)

Comment: yeah, i had already changed the default bower path using .bowerc file to vendor/bower_components.

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate your reply. I saw a video on laracasts explaining how to copy across bower files, and it showed G Way using copy function without full path. Then, when i saw the config file and it had the vendor/bower_components, i guessed that was the intended behaviour.  I think the video might be out of date however, as I think it was made when bower was baked in to the framework. Thank once again for your help

Comment: @everythingbeforethebutis...  Jeffrey Way actually uses  undocumented ``publish()`` method in that laracast. https://i.imgur.com/djlS2Zj.png